# Property placeholder resolution precedence when using vault and consul

Tags: spring-cloud-consul, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have question about placeholder resolution priority when using `consul-config` and `vault-config`
I created simple app using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958207/trying-to-get-spring-consul-vault-to-work-together) information

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config')

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Note that I'm not using service discovery.

Doing next step I created property `foo.prop = consul` (in consul storage)
and `foo.prop = vault`.

When using:

```
@Value("${foo.prop}")
private String prop;
```

I'm getting `vault` as an output, but when I delete `foo.prop` from vault and restart app, I will get `consul`.

I did this few times in different combinations and seems vault config has higher priority over consul.

My question is where I can find information about resolving strategy.(Imagine that we added as third `zookeeper-config`). Seems spring-core documentation keep quiet about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood by debugging the Spring source code... Now Vault has a priority.

My investigation results:
[PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/config/PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java) is responsible to initialize all property sources in bootstrap phase. Before locating properties it sorts all propertySourceLocators by Order:

```
AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(this.propertySourceLocators);
```

Vault always "wins" because instance of [LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/blob/master/spring-cloud-vault-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.java) (at least this one was created during my debugging) implements `PriorityOrdered` interface. Instance of [ConsulPropertySourceLocator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java) has `@Order(0)` annotation. According to [OrderComparator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/OrderComparator.java) : instance of PriorityOrdered is 'more important'.

In case you have another PriorityOrdered property source (e.g. custom one) you can influence this order by setting `spring.cloud.vault.config.order` for Vault.

For now without customization I don't know how to change priority between Vault and Consul.